# draw picture using LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

[image]

I try to draw the following picture using LaTeX.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If it's the case you should provide what you tried

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If you would like our help, a question is usually good to use, not just a statement. Second, to echo @RomainPicot's statement, showing us your approach makes it easier for us to answer and better for you to understand.

Comment: why do you want to draw it? at least the left hand half looks as if it would be better just included as an image.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}


\includegraphics[height=100pt]{core}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)\tiny
\put(0,100){\line(1,0){40}}
\put(0,55){\line(1,0){30}}
\put(0,42){\line(1,0){40}}
\put(10,102){Surface du xx}
\put(10,95){Zone raxhvxkcv}
\put(10,70){\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}ZONE\\NON\\SATUREE\end{tabular}}
\put(10,30){\ldots\ \ldots}
\end{picture}


\end{document}
```